# Google tag manger tag setting for a website with multiple languages

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

What is the best practice for setting GTM tags for a website with multiple languages, in which case the website has different sub domain such as /en_eu/; /fr_eu/; /de_eu/; /it_eu/; and currently having one property in GA4 and one single GTM container:
For example I have a website that has 4 main languages, and I want to track the views of a certain product in the 4 languages, taking in consideration that the same product has different names in the 4 languages.

I tried to create a single trigger for the same product, using the same product name in the 4 languages and set it as page view, trigger fires when page URL fires when URL matches RegEX the product name in different languages